# WMI Host Provider Credentials

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory, wmi

Numerous times per hour, a user on the a domain is getting locked out by WmiPrvSE.exe. Digging into the Event Log on the server that is locking out the user, it shows that WmiPrvSE.exe is using explicit credentials, as opposed to a Local System Account. Examining the processes and services, they all say that they are using a local system account. However, the lockout keeps happening from that process.

Is there a way to remove the user's credentials from the process to prevent this happening going forward? I have removed any traces of the user from the server (user profiles, stored credentials, etc).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the symptom in a clean boot environment to troubleshoot whether the issue is caused by a third party service.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

We could try to use process explorer tool to analyze the "WmiPrvSE.exe" service.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx